# Trigger after update: System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Tags: trigger, error, error-messages, before-trigger, after-trigger

I have a trigger:

```
   if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for(SomeRecord__c newRecord : Trigger.new){
            if(Trigger.oldMap.get(newRecord.Id).Worker__c != newRecord.Worker__c){
                if(newRecord.Worker__c != NULL){
                    newRecord.WorkersNotes__c = newRecord.Worker__r.WorkersNotes__c;
                } else{
                    newRecord.WorkersNotes__c = '';
                }    
            }
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying to update `newRecord.Worker__c`, I'm getting `System.FinalException: Record is read-only`. If I make it `before update`, nothing will happen. What is wrong here?

P.S. `WorkersNotes__c` is a Long Text Area, so I can't use the formula field.

And yes: my question and this `Exeception on After Insert, Record is read only` are not the same. I'm talking about `after/before update`, not about `after insert`.

Comment: you can't update the record in `trigger.after` context, can you give more explanation about `WorkersNotes__c` filed update?

Comment: It's just a Long Text Area for both objects, and when the child changes it's parent, the new parent gives his `WorkersNotes__c` to this child.

Comment: that means when ever Parent `SomeRecord__c `  WorkersNotes__c  field updates/add newvalue you need to update/insert same value in to child `Cleaner__r`  WorkersNotes__c field same like vice versa? is it right ?

Comment: `SomeRecord__c` - is a child. The child has just 1 parent. And if it had `Worker 1` before and then changed this Lookup Field to `Worker 2` - we need to change this field: `newRecord.WorkersNotes__c = newRecord.Worker__r.WorkersNotes__c`. No `Cleaner` there, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update the "new" objects in the before phase. You should typically:

1. validate and/or update the given objects via the Trigger.new or Trigger.newMap in before phase
2. update objects related to the Trigger.new or Trigger.newMap objects in after phase

I recommend this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. Okay. I make it know with `before update`. And I'm getting nothing. No changes. When I'm trying to update the record I'm getting `DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old`.

Comment: @Apelsinova Have you changed the if condition accordingly?

Comment: If you are using before update phase and are making changes to the Trigger.new objects there is no need to perform an extra DML update operation in the trigger to have these changes committed - I'm guessing you have an update statement in your trigger code, which is what is going wrong.